# How to add adobe reader plugin in chrome linux

Tags: linux, adobe-flash, plugin

I have installed adobe acrobat reader in my linux machine(lite). How to acrobat reader to chrome. I tried in the chrome settings (extension->developer mode->load unpacked extension)but what file to browse to add the adobe as plugin . I googled there I found it should have `.crx` extension but in adobe folder I din't find any crx file.

File structure  filesystem->opt->lampp,google,adobe

Comment: You're confusing plugins and extensions. Check `chrome://plugins/` to see if it's not already installed.

Comment: There is no adobe reader plugin so that I installed adobe reader in linux machine. Now how to add installed adobe reader to chrome

Comment: Use your package manager to install the acroread plugin for Mozilla browsers. It's also compatible with Chrome.

Comment: Package manager not listing acroread plugin itself

Comment: Are you using Chrome, or Chormium? Chrome has a built-in PDF viewer, actually. Doesn't that work? Otherwise, there's [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn?hl=en) which may be more convenient than Acrobat Reader.